# Integrals of products of fractional parts

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $((x)):=x-\lfloor x \rfloor -1/2$, where $\lfloor x \rfloor $ denotes the greatest integer $\le x$. 
Let $a,b,c,...$ denote arbitrary natural numbers. It is clear that
$$ \int_0^a ((x/a)) dx =0.$$
A little exercise shows that 
$$ \int_0^{ab} ((x/a))((x/b)) dx =\frac{\gcd(a,b)^2}{12}.$$
It appears that 
$$ \int_0^{abc} ((x/a))((x/b))((x/c)) dx =0,$$
but I have not been able to determine a general formula for 
$$ \int_0^{abcd} ((x/a))((x/b))((x/c))((x/d))dx.$$
I would be interested in a general formula for the last integral, and for similar integrals with a larger number of factors. It seems that these integrals, or the corresponding sums, such as
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{ab-1} ((k/a))((k/b)) =  \frac{\gcd(a,b)^2-1}{12},$$
should be in the literature, but I have not been able to find a reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One place where I have seen this come up is in a paper of [Lemke Oliver and Soundararajan](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.06168).  Here such quantities appear naturally in computing moments of some remainder terms, and Proposition 3.1 gives some basic properties.  The sums are very closely related to the integrals (see Proposition 3.2 there).  These are not too hard to establish, and I don't know really anything non-trivial about these integrals.  I think it would be quite interesting to understand even the four fold integrals better.

Comment: In particular, a closed-form for the four-fold integral would lead to an asymptotic for the fourth moment of the error term for partial sums of the Euler totient function. (Eric Naslund, Maksym Radziwiłł, and I all looked at this a long time ago but didn't go anywhere.)

Answer (score 6):

These quantities are studied under the name Franel Integrals in the literature. If we change notation so that $\psi(x) = x−⌊x⌋−1/2 $ is the saw tooth function, we may define the "fourth order" Franel integral as

$I(a,b,c,d)=\int_{0}^{1} \psi(ax) \psi(bx) \psi(cx) \psi(dx) dx.$

Expanding $\psi(x)$ in a Fourier series we see that:

$I(a,b,c,d) = \frac{1}{16 \pi^4} \sum_{\substack{s,t,u,v \in Z - \{0\}\\ sa+tb+uc+ue=0}} \frac{1}{stuv} =: \frac{1}{16 \pi^4} L(a,b,c,d)$

There is no explicit general closed form evaluation of this quantity but there are many special cases known, including

$L(1,1,1,1) = \frac{\pi^4}{5},$

$L(a,1,1,1) = \left(\frac{1}{3a} - \frac{2}{15a^3} \right) \pi^4,$

$L(a,a,b,b) = \frac{\pi^4}{9} + \frac{8 (a,b)^4 \zeta(4)}{a^2b^2}.$

Comment: Do similar identities to your final identity hold for other numbers of variables?

Comment: The "general identity" is, as far as I can see, essentially a consequence of expanding the function into a Fourier series and using orthogonality of the trigonometric system. This is how the integral is transformed into a counting problem for solutions of linear Diophantine equations. You can certainly do a similar thing for any other number of variables, but the formula clearly becomes a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to Franel integrals. That's very helpful. But there is something wrong with your formulas, because $I(1,1,1,1)=1/80$.

Comment: Andreas: indeed I was off by a factor of $\pi^4/16$ in my identities. I've corrected this now.

Comment: Mark: Thanks for the correction. But $I(2,1,1,1)=3/320$, while your formula says that it equals $1/120$. Do you have a reference for these formulas?

Comment: Andreas: indeed that was another typo, $L(a,1,1,1) = \left(\frac{1}{3a} - \frac{2}{15a^3} \right) \pi^4$. I've updated the posted. See: R. McIntosh's paper Franel Integrals of Order Four.